# Is there a class in bada which is similar to "Context" in android?

Tags: android, android-context, bada

I'm changing a project from android to bada, but I don't find a class which has the same effect as "Context". Any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us what Context does on Android

Answer (score 1):

I guess the application's main class (deriving from `Osp::App::Application`) will do the job?